# what should relation between two classes be?

Tags: language-agnostic, uml

I have two classes namely;

```
  --------------              -------------------
     class  A                     class B
  --------------              -------------------
                                  int c
  --------------              -------------------


  --------------              -------------------
```

`class A` is responsible for taking input from user, and `class B` is responsible for storing input token by `class A`.

What should the relation be between them?

There are direct relations between them:

- `class A` function takes input then this input is directly stored in `class B`.
- One of `class A`'s functions is *friend* of `class B`.

Comment: This is not about C++, is it?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I am implementing it with c++

Comment: @jques: UML is language-agnostic.

Comment: What is your use case? What is the data being processed? Depending on your answers, you might be better off with one class to handle both operations.

Comment: So, is there even a direct relation between those two classes? Do `A` or `B` require to be aware of the other (e.g.: have an instance), or is there a class in the middle that calls `A`, then `B`?

Answer (score -1):

There are three possibilities:

- A could access B (perhaps via an interface) to store the data it produces;
- B could access A (perhaps via an interface) to fetch the data it stores;
- They could be unrelated, with higher-level business logic fetching data from A and storing it in B.

The third would be my preference, since it makes the objects self-contained and easier to test in isolation, and more flexible since they are not constrained to act together in a particular way.

Answer (score -1):

With the limited info provided, I am assuming a scenario here:

Since you want Class A to be storing/setting some data residing inside of an object of Class B, probably Class A would need to use a setter method from Class B. This is a 'uses' relationship and could be categorized as **association** relationship.

If class A is also responsible to create instances of Class B, then the relationship would be **aggregation**.